# Shard on subset of id's fields

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a document of which the identifier (`_id`) is a document itself. For example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "userIdentifier": 50,
        "eventIdentifier": 47
    },
    "location": "New York",
    "outcome": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Is it possible with this kind of document and id definition to apply hash sharding on `_id.userIdentifier`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can shard on that field as long as you have created an index on the field, and it exists in every document.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to create a separate index, or will the implicit unique index on `{_id.userIdentifier, _id.eventIdentifier}` be used? As `_id.userIdentifier` is a prefix of that, it should be possible and feasible to use that?

Comment: In recent MongoDB version the shard key can be also missing.

Comment: If by default index you mean the one on `{_id:1}` then the field is not a prefix, so that won't work.

Comment: But be aware, `$merge` (and perhaps some other) operation still requires a value on shard key, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-51207

Comment: It's unfortunate that the unique index on `_id` cannot be used here. I guess this index indexes the document as an opaque value?

Comment: Exactly.  Also note that the order of fields matters.  If you reverse the fields in one of the _id objects, it will be a new unique value.